Unable to ping URL from gitbash
I am unable to ping any URL in gitbash but however the same URL's are opening in browser on same machine, how should I fix this.
I tried setting the proxy using the below command but still it doesnt work. How should i check where the request is getting blocked?
Command to set proxy:
git config --global http.proxy
http://proxyUsername@proxy.server.com:port
git config --global https.proxy
https://proxyUsername@proxy.server.com:port



Try google - https://www.google.com/search?q=How+should+i+check+where+ping+is+getting+blocked.

Ping uses ICMP, which is different than TCP (notably there's no port number).
So unless you are familiar with the network topology, ping not working is not a good indicator that there is a network problem.
If you are on an intranet, you can discuss this with your administrator, but the trend has been to disable ICMP, usually for security or administrative concerns.
